# How to call a function dynamically?

Tags: angularjs

I need to call a function dynamically in scope, for:

```
$scope.myFunction1= function(){}
$scope.myFunction2= function(){}
```

I need to set an attribute in the directive like:

```
<my-directive func-name="myFunction1"></my-directive>
```

So that I can specify which function to call without using if statement

```
// then to call the function as:
$scope[attrs["funcName"]]();
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Just try the code at least once before asking a question.

Comment: Read about binding functions in directives (represented by '&') in angular docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's even easier if you bind the attribute to a scope variable with a text binding.

```
scope: {
  funcName: '@'
},
controller: function() {
  $scope[$scope.funcName]();
}
```

Although this seems like an anti-pattern, when Angular already has support for passing a function directly. What are you actually trying to achieve here? Where is the function name coming from?

Comment: `@` binding? I don't think so. :)

Comment: Eh? It's been a while since I've used Angular. `@` binds the text value of the attribute, right?

Comment: Yes, that it does. How will it help call a function?

Comment: Because OP is passing the name of a function that exists on the inner scope to the directive.

Comment: Yes, I realized that now. Anyhow, that is not the right way to call a function. If we're talking isolate scopes here, `&` binding is a much better choice, isn't it?

Comment: Yeah, Javascript has reflection. All you need is the name of a property to access it. OP doesn't want to pass a function or evaluate an expression. I don't know why.

Comment: Maybe just poor articulation on his part. I'm pretty sure he wants the `&` binding.

Comment: Probably, I edited my answer to ask for more details.

Answer (score -1):

You can use switch case, I think its efficient than any conditional statement

```
$scope.fun1(){}
$scope.func2(){}

function callFun(funcName){
switch(funcName){
case'func1':{
$scope.func1();
break;
}
case'func2':{
$scope.func2();
break;
}

}
}
```

Comment: Switch/case **is** a conditional statement.

Comment: I was saying any other conditional statement